# Accesing file in Mapper through Distributed Cache

Tags: hadoop

I want to access the contents of the distributed file in my Mapper. Below is the code I have written which generates the name of the file for Distributed Cache. Please help me accessing the contents of the file

```
   public class DistCacheExampleMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text >
     {
      Text a = new Text();
    Path[] dates = new Path[0];
    public void configure(JobConf conf) {

    try {
            dates = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
            String astr = dates.toString();
            a = new Text(astr);

          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Caught exception while getting cached files: " +   
          StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
          }


    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, 
           Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

             String line = value.toString();

             for(Path cacheFile: dates){

                    output.collect(new Text(line), new Text(cacheFile.getName()));

                }



                }


            }
```

Comment: what I want to do is I have a file which I am passing to Mapper. I want to compare 1st column of each row of that file with Distributed cache file. If it is present in that file, I want to pass it to reducer else not.

Comment: How are columns defined in your file? What do you want to compare? The whole file in the Distributed Cache?

Comment: Yes I want to compare the whole file. I want to add a csv file to distributed cache so that every mapper has it. Please tell me how can I read it in my mapper code as csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead in your configure() method:

```
List<String []> lines; 
Path[] files = new Path[0];

public void configure(JobConf conf) {
    lines = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader SW;
    try {
        files = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
        SW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[0].toString()));
        String line;
        while ((line = SW.readLine()) != null) {
           lines.add(line.split(",")); //now, each lines entry is a String array, with each element being a column
        }
        SW.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Caught exception while getting cached files: " +   
        StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
    }
}
```

This way, you will have the contents of the files (in this case the first file) in the Distributed Cache, in the variable `lines`. Each `lines` entry represent a String array, which is split by ','. So the first column of the first row is `lines.get(0)[0]`, the third row of the second line is `lines.get(1)[2]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Have you worked on Distributed Cache in Pig. If yes, please help me. I want to do this thing in Pig. how can i do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, so that others can see what solution worked for you.

Comment: I want to compare the whole file. I want to add a csv file to distributed cache so that every mapper has it. Please tell me how can I read it in my mapper code as csv file.

Comment: If I have more than one file to be read in Distributed cache, where to make changes, Please tell.

Comment: I know I have to add DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/user/hduser/dc_input/allfiles.zip"), conf); in the driver code. But I want tos tore all the contents of all the flies in the string listarray. Please tell me how to read all the files in mapper and store in the string list.